# Pyomo saying my model is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pyomo

Hi I'm testing my Pyomo installation and when I try to solve any optimization problem, it returns an error that reads:

> "Exiting pyomo solve: A model is not defined and the 'pyomo_create_model' is not provided in module test.py"

I'm executing

> pyomo solve test.py diet.dat --solver=glpk

```
from pyomo.environ import *
infinity = float('inf')

model = AbstractModel()

# Foods
model.F = Set()
# Nutrients
model.N = Set()

# Cost of each food
model.c    = Param(model.F, within=PositiveReals)
# Amount of nutrient in each food
model.a    = Param(model.F, model.N, within=NonNegativeReals)
# Lower and upper bound on each nutrient
model.Nmin = Param(model.N, within=NonNegativeReals, default=0.0)
model.Nmax = Param(model.N, within=NonNegativeReals, default=infinity)
# Volume per serving of food
model.V    = Param(model.F, within=PositiveReals)
# Maximum volume of food consumed
model.Vmax = Param(within=PositiveReals)

# Number of servings consumed of each food
model.x = Var(model.F, within=NonNegativeIntegers)

# Minimize the cost of food that is consumed
def cost_rule(model):
    return sum(model.c[i]*model.x[i] for i in model.F)
model.cost = Objective(rule=cost_rule)

# Limit nutrient consumption for each nutrient
def nutrient_rule(model, j):
    value = sum(model.a[i,j]*model.x[i] for i in model.F)
    return model.Nmin[j] <= value <= model.Nmax[j]
model.nutrient_limit = Constraint(model.N, rule=nutrient_rule)

# Limit the volume of food consumed
def volume_rule(model):
    return sum(model.V[i]*model.x[i] for i in model.F) <= model.Vmax
model.volume = Constraint(rule=volume_rule)
```

and my diet.dat file is

```
param:  F:                          c     V  :=
  "Cheeseburger"                 1.84   4.0  
  "Ham Sandwich"                 2.19   7.5  
  "Hamburger"                    1.84   3.5  
  "Fish Sandwich"                1.44   5.0  
  "Chicken Sandwich"             2.29   7.3  
  "Fries"                         .77   2.6  
  "Sausage Biscuit"              1.29   4.1  
  "Lowfat Milk"                   .60   8.0 
  "Orange Juice"                  .72  12.0 ;

param Vmax := 75.0;

param:  N:       Nmin   Nmax :=
        Cal      2000      .
        Carbo     350    375
        Protein    55      .
        VitA      100      .
        VitC      100      .
        Calc      100      .
        Iron      100      . ;

param a:
                               Cal  Carbo Protein   VitA   VitC  Calc  Iron :=
  "Cheeseburger"               510     34     28     15      6    30    20
  "Ham Sandwich"               370     35     24     15     10    20    20
  "Hamburger"                  500     42     25      6      2    25    20
  "Fish Sandwich"              370     38     14      2      0    15    10
  "Chicken Sandwich"           400     42     31      8     15    15     8
  "Fries"                      220     26      3      0     15     0     2
  "Sausage Biscuit"            345     27     15      4      0    20    15
  "Lowfat Milk"                110     12      9     10      4    30     0
  "Orange Juice"                80     20      1      2    120     2     2 ;
```

How do I fix the no model error? In the 3rd line of code in test.py the model is defined

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your solver or you don't put your test.py and diet.dat in the same directory.

Here is my results:

```
hidden@hidden:~/Desktop$ pyomo solve test.py diet.dat --solver=gurobi
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
[    0.00] Creating model
[    0.03] Applying solver
[    0.65] Processing results
    Number of solutions: 1
    Solution Information
      Gap: 0.0
      Status: optimal
      Function Value: 15.049999999999999
    Solver results file: results.json
[    0.65] Applying Pyomo postprocessing actions
[    0.65] Pyomo Finished
```

PS: I copy/pasted your code and changed nothing.